# Are bootstrap 4.6 buttons supposed to have inset shadow on active?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The [Bootstrap 4.6 spec says](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/buttons/#active-state)

> Buttons will appear pressed (with a darker background, darker border, and **inset shadow**) when active

On inspecting I didn't see any inset box shadow being applied. Not only that, doing `ctrl + F` on the whole [bootstrap css file](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/dist/css/bootstrap.css)  for `inset` keyword doesn't match anything.

Are we really supposed to have an inset/inner shadow, or is it a typo?

---

P.S: I've added this as an [issue on github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/34859#issue-984116010).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this code where the box-shadow appear when you click on button. You can remove the box shadow. This active box shadow on focus.

```
    .btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #0069d9;
        border-color: #0062cc;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(38 143 255 / 50%);
    }
```

```
    .btn.focus, .btn:focus {
        outline: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(0 123 255 / 25%);
    }
```

Comment: This is an outer box-shadow, not the inset/inner box shadow I am talking about in the question.

Comment: Then it should be a background color not inset box shadow check the same code there is also a background color on focus.

Comment: Background-color is completely different from inset shadow. My question is only about inset-shadow.

Comment: Just need to write inset in the box-shadow

.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.2rem rgb(0 123 255 / 25%);
    }

Comment: The question is not _how to apply inset box-shadow_; the question is does bootstrap **mean** to put `inset` shadow on active buttons? Did they forget to implement in the code?